# How can I send order details of products to mongodb?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, react-redux, mern

how can I make the 2 orders or more to one order and send the data to mongodb??
for example in picture i have two title of products how can I make the two titles in one text for example : { title : "Oats Walnut bites" , "Cornflakes bites" } and put it in mongodb in one order

Answer (score 0):

Please consider store the data using string or array.

```
 { title : "Oats Walnut bites,Cornflakes bites" }; // use title.split(',') to read

or

 { title : ["Oats Walnut bites","Cornflakes bites"] };
```